# What is the Python time string format for this?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

I am trying to find the correct time format for this time string for the Python time module:

```
'2019-01-25T06:59:36.8081116Z'
```

I tried this `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` and many variants and can't get it right.

Link to the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: could you add more context to your code and maybe what the error message was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
import datetime
curtime = datetime.datetime.now()
curtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

couldn't figure out how to get 7 decimal places. Maybe your string ends with '6Z' instead of 'Z'?

Comment: I'm trying to do: `import time` and then `time.strptime('2019-01-25T06:59:36.8081116Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")` to get time struct but it's not working. Error is ValueError: time data '2019-01-23T06:59:36.8081116Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

Comment: time doesn't have %f